# angular 6 The specified command ("deploy") is invalid. For a list of available options, run "ng help"

Tags: json, angular5, npm-scripts, angular6

I have migrated my Angular 5 app to Angular 6. It is working fine except custom scripts in `package.json`.

When I use `ng deploy` in the terminal, it is showing the below error:

> The specified command ("deploy") is invalid. For a list of available options, run "ng help". Did you mean "help"?

Below is my package.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "ngsw-config": "node_modules/.bin/ngsw-config dist src/ngsw-config.json",
    "ngsw-copy": "cp node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-worker.js dist/",
    "deploy": "ng build --prod && npm run ngsw-config && npm run ngsw-copy"
},
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be running `npm run deploy`? The `package.json` scripts go along with npm not Angular's CLI (`ng`)

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel W Strimpel. working ..

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `npm run deploy`.

Not all commands from package.json are related to `ng`

Comment: This helps a lot could you explain why npm run not ng or just npm